# How to make Rest API call to application when i deploy in Websphere server?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am able to Deploy the my JAX-RS Jersey application into WebSphere server but when I make sample rest rest api call , its giving follow error .

Url is : http://:9080//hello/santhosh

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Error Is :

```
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /hello/santhosh.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Change your <url-pattern> to * and test.

Comment: I tryed it , its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you  deploy your application on any server you will have a name for it (at least the name of the war file). Let us assume your application is deployed as **myApp** on websphere. Then your call should look like

```
http://HostName:9080/myApp/hello/santhosh
```

if the @Path annotation on your resource class points to **santhosh**.

Comment: Yes ," http://Hopstname:9080/appINFO/hello/santhosh"   , Here appINFO is my application name

Answer (score 0):

If your only servlet mapping is for /rest/ you'd think your client would have to be requesting something /rest/-relative.

Answer (score 0):

If your app's context root is "appINFO" (from one of the comments), and your servlet mapping is "/rest/*", then you should reach your app by calling http://:9080/appINFO/rest/hello/santhosh.  Just put the appropriate value for the host.

**Edit**:  If you're deploying in WebSphere Liberty, you don't need to use Jersey, so it should simplify your deployment and the libraries you need.  Take a look at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_jaxrs_implementation.html) which explains step-by-step how to do that.

Comment: I have tryed above url also but its not working its giving uncaught servlet excpetion 500 error

Comment: I edited my answer with a suggestion that should simplify your deployment.